# Set Relations (anti-symmetrical)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to determine whether the relation $R$ on the set of all people is antisymmetric where $(a,b)$ is an element of $R$ if and only if

```
(a) a is taller than b.  
(b) a and b are born on the same day.  
(c) a has the same first name as b.  
(d) a and b have a common grandparent.
```

Can someone give me a simple explanation of antisymmetry and where to get started here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to help by formulating the relations as sets and recapitulating the definition of antisymmetry:

$$R \text{ is antisymmetric iff } \forall\ (x,y) \in R : (y,x) \notin R$$

---

**Mathematical formulations:**
$$\begin{align*}
R & = \{ (a,b) | {\rm size}(a) > {\rm size}(b) \} \tag{a} \\
R & = \{ (a,b) | {\rm birthday}(a) = {\rm birthday}(b)\} \tag{b} \\
R & = \{ (a,b) | {\rm first name}(a) = {\rm first name}(b) \} \tag{c} \\
R & = \{ (a,b) | {\rm grandparents}(a) \cap {\rm grandparents}(b) \neq \emptyset \} \tag{d}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Ok, so for the first example, I believe R would be anti-symmetric since when X is taller than Y, Y can't be taller than X, making it anti-symmetric. Right?

Comment: @user2461994 Your observation is correct. How about the rest?

Comment: For (b) It is not Anti-symmetric.  If X is born on the same day as Y is an element of R, Y being born on the same day as X is also an element of R.

Comment: (c) is also not anti-symmetric.  If X has the same first name as Y, it follows Y has the same first name as X.

Comment: (d) It is not anti-symmetric because if X and Y have a common grandparent, Y must have a common grandparent with X.

Comment: Jep, all good. Now a little bonus: Which of these are symmetric? ;)

Comment: (B), (C), and (D)?

Comment: That's true. Notice that if a relation is symmetric _and_ antisymmetric, it must be $R=\emptyset$.